# How to arrange columns position and order on different screen size on Bootstrap?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive-design, grid

I know Bootstrap supports responsive design by using classes sm,md,lg for their grid system. I know they can also swap columns that goes to the next row by using push and pull. 
But I'm asking if anyone has a better idea of arranging the columns on this scenario.
Column B should span two rows -- It will hold texts while col A, B will contain images.

On big screen

COL A | COL B

COL C | COL B

On smaller screen

COL A
COL B
COL C

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How if you create 2 Col B, but 1 is hidden when the screen is large, and 1 is hidden when the screen is small.

```
    <div class="col-lg-6">
        <div>
            A
        </div>
        <div class="hidden-lg">
            <img width=100 height=100 />
        </div>
        <div>
            C
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6 visible-lg">
        <img width=100 height=100 />
    </div>
```

Comment: Good idea but I want column B to be always shown because it is a text and I dont want to duplicate contents on the other B.Maybe I can find a way to hide and show C instead, because it uses an image which I can just reuse.

Comment: Yup, you can do it at that way too :)